# Return Array From SwingWorker Thread to Main Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, java-threads

I have a Swing GUI that when it open it performs a a thread in the background. For that I used `SwingWorker` thread. the problem is that I have an Array of String declare in main thread that is expected to collect information from swing worker thread and return that but after the thread is finishes the array is still empty. I guess once the thread is finished the array looses its values even though the array is declare in the main thread.

How can I return the values of the array to the main thread?

```
ArrayList<String> allnets = new ArrayList();
new SwingWorker<Object, Void>() {           
    @Override
    public Object doInBackground() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        System.out.println("interfaces");
        netAdapter = new NetInterface();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int i = 0; i < allnets.length; i++) {
            allnets.add("interface number");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {                

    }   
}.execute();
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
//      String[] inetfaces = {"eth0", "eth1", "wlan1", "wlan2", "wlan3"};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(allnets);
comboBox.setToolTipText("Interfaces");
comboBox.setBounds(444, 51, 137, 22);
frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
```

Comment: According to the code you posted, method `doInBackground()` returns null. So how do you want to populate your array?

Comment: You want a _Swing_ application that contains a `JComboBox` that displays all the network interface names, correct?

Comment: @Abra yes that's correct

Comment: Don't know why CKing deleted their answer. It's basically correct. The `SwingWorker...execute()` call returns _immediately_, as in, _before_ the worker thread calls `doInBackground`. Meanwhile, your main thread already is trying to use the `allnets` list, before the worker has had a chance to populate it.

Comment: Don't know much Swing anymore, but I think you want to move the code that creates the `comboBox` into the `SwingWorker...done()` method. Swing will ensure that the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) calls `done()` only _after_ the worker thread has completed the `doInBackground()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of all interface names, call [static] method `getNetworkInterfaces()` of class `java.net.NetworkInterface`. And I assume you want to call that method from inside a `SwingWorker`. Also, from the code you posted, I assume you want to populate the `JComboBox` in the `done()` method of class `SwingWorker`. And since all the work is being done in the `SwingWorker` class, method `doInBackground()` doesn't need to return anything.

When it comes to using `SwingWorker`, I prefer to make a completely separate class that extends `SwingWorker` and not an anonymous inner class.

Here is the code for a *Swing* application. The `JFrame` displays a `JLabel` and a `JComboBox`. The `JcomboBox` contains the list of the names of all the network interfaces.

Note that on my Windows 10 (64 bit) machine running JDK 13, populating the `JComboBox` takes hardly any time at all, so the `SwingWorker` is not really needed. I guess you just want to practice using `SwingWorker`, correct?

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SwngWrkr implements Runnable {
    private JComboBox<Object> combo;
    private JFrame frame;

    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Interfaces"));
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>();
        model.addElement("Loading...");
        combo = new JComboBox<Object>(model);
        mainPanel.add(combo);
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("SW");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new GetIfTsk(combo).execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwngWrkr instance = new SwngWrkr();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}

class GetIfTsk extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private JComboBox<Object> combo;
    private List<Object> netIfNames;

    public GetIfTsk(JComboBox<Object> combo) {
        this.combo = combo;
        netIfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifs = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        int ndx = 0;
        while (ifs.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface ni = ifs.nextElement();
            String name = ni.getName();
            System.out.printf("%2d. %s%n", ++ndx, name);
            netIfNames.add(name);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void done() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Object> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>) combo.getModel();
        model.removeAllElements();
        model.addAll(netIfNames);
        model.setSelectedItem(netIfNames.get(0));
    }
}
```